# Creating a 3D map starting from a .asc file

Tags: java, c#, 3d

I have a Digital Terrain Model in .asc format. It's basically a matrix of points, and every point has it's altitude stored. So I'm looking for a library (or something to use) to create a 3d map starting from this file. I'd prefer to use either c# or Java.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library support that format.

http://www.jpct.net/about.html